# spring boot hsqldb details

Tags: spring-boot, hsqldb

I have created two spring boot microservices for experimenting purposes, both use hsqldb. Is there a way to see the hsqldb details like what is the name of the db that spring boot created, username, password, what tables are there in each one and to query those tables.

Comment: I found this way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78200773/showing-console-of-hsqldb-as-h2-spring-boot-3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/78207406/811293

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in SQL functions and INFORMATION_SCHEMA views in HSQLDB to check these properties. See the Guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/

But the quick and easy way is to use a `file:` database connection and check the `*.script` file of the database, which contains SQL statements that set the properties and create the tables.