# Showing Console of hsqldb as H2, Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hsqldb, dbeaver, in-memory-database

I'm trying to use **`hsqldb`** like in-memory database.

In my `build.gradle` file, you can see the version:

```
implementation group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '2.7.2'
```

In my `application.yml` file, I have:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ms-people

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver
    url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    #database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

In the Log, I obtained:

```
Hibernate: drop table if exists phones cascade 
Hibernate: drop table if exists users cascade 
Hibernate: create table phones (city_code integer, country_code integer, id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), number bigint, user_id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table users (isactive boolean not null, created timestamp(6), id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), last_login timestamp(6), modified timestamp(6), email varchar(255) unique, name varchar(255), password varchar(255), token varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table phones add constraint FKmg6d77tgqfen7n1g763nvsqe3 foreign key (user_id) references users
```

But, when I tryied to connect and see my database and table. I can't see nothing.

**How I would see the executed query/command?**

**What are my mistakes?**

[image]

**EDIT**

I was reading this post https://www.baeldung.com/java-in-memory-databases

- H2 Database
- HSQLDB (HyperSQL Database)
- Apache Derby Database
- SQLite Database

And I was testing with `H2`:
In my `build.gradle` file, you can see the version:

```
runtimeOnly group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version: '2.2.224'
```

In my `application.yml` file, I have:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: ms-people
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    username: sa
    password:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    generate-ddl: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
```

[image]

**Alternatively to H2, what other could be shown as H2 allow us?**

Comment: Because it is an in-memory database. Both your application **and** DBEaver are looking at their own instance of the in-memory database. You cannot remotely connect to the inmemory db of the application.

Answer (score 1):

For `HSQLDB (HyperSQL Database)`
I found this article https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-view-content-of-hsqldb-embedded-database/

```
package org.bz.app.mspeople.configurations;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import org.hsqldb.util.DatabaseManagerSwing;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SpringRootConfig {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    //default username : sa, password : ''
    @PostConstruct
    public void getDbManager() {
        DatabaseManagerSwing.main(
                new String[]{"--url", "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb", "--user", "sa", "--password", ""});

    }

}
```

and this class:

```
package org.bz.app.mspeople.configurations;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabase;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        //jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                //.addScript("db/hsqldb/db.sql")
                .build();
        return db;
    }

}
```

and this link: https://gist.github.com/fredjoseph/0d9eabb60860b12ba7b7adbfd4d0c558

*Then, we need to add the following VM arguments **-Djava.awt.headless=false** when the application is started*

I'm using IntelliJ:

[image]

I was testing:

[image]